# how to fix established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond error in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package that is used to transfer table data from the test to the production server every week.
The total item count is 41712958.
For a few weeks this package is throwing the below error:

> [OLE DB Source [39]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE
> DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
> available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream". An
> OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
> Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Protocol error in TDS
> stream". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server
> Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication
> link failure". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
> Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP
> Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
> not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond.".

Few weeks back, it used to work fine, kindly help how should I fix this issue?
server has: 4GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Why still use the SQL Server Native Client as it is deprecated. Try changing the OLE DB provider from `SQL Server Native Client` to `Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server`.

From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The previous Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (SQLOLEDB) and SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider (SQLNCLI) remains deprecated and **it is not recommended to use** either for new development work.

Comment: Thanks Hadi! 
could you please help me to understand If update 'SQL Server Native Client', will it impact the existing SSIS project?

Comment: @user5297806 I dont think it affect anything

Comment: Worth to note if you're using ODBC: the replacement is likely the "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" for the deprecated NCLI

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but setting CommandTimeout = 0 in SSIS on the source helped me with a similar error.